# Why does typing $ in fish shell show the error "Unknown command: bind_dollar"?

Tags: shell, fish

I am running fishshell 3.5.1 on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1
I can work most all commands just fine but whenever I try to type in the dollar sign (even before pressing Return) I get the error: *"Unknown command: bind_dollar"*

I've tried:

- Reinstalling w/Homebrew
- Confirming that fish is in PATH
- Deleting my fish.config

Below is the output of my issue and setup:

**This happens as soon as I type a dollar sign:**

`$ fish: Unknown command: bind_dollar`

**Fish config directory:**

```
~/.config/fish
$ ls
completions/    conf.d/         config.fish     fish_variables  functions/
```

**Using /bin/sh to examine my $PATH:**

```
$ /bin/sh
sh-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

**Ensuring fish is located in PATH:**

```
sh-3.2$ whereis fish
fish: /usr/local/bin/fish
```

**Viewing the contents of my fish.config (which is the default version):**

```
sh-3.2$ cat config.fish
if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
end
```

Comment: You might be looking for https://sourceforge.net/p/fish/mailman/message/34464536/

Comment: To find where that binding is set `grep -r bind_dollar ~/.config/fish`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Glenn's comment, I was able to track down the issue:

Running:

```
grep -r bind_dollar ~/.config/fish
```

Returned:

```
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish
```

Which contained:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
      ### bang-bang ###
      bind ! bind_bang
      bind $ bind_dollar # <-- removing this line fixed the issue
      ### bang-bang ###
  end
```

Removing the "bind_dollar" line fixed the issue.